# Postgres: ¿Cómo utilizar un array como variable?

Tags: base-de-datos, postgresql

Estoy haciendo un script .sql

```
DO $$
  DECLARE 
    lista_usuarios integer[] = (select usuario_id from usuario where estado = 'ACTIVO');
BEGIN
    CREATE CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW cuentas_con_usuarios_activos AS
    select * from cuentas where cuenta_usuario IN (lista_usuarios);
    ...

    CREATE CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW cuentas_con_usuarios_inactivos AS
    select * from cuentas where cuenta_usuario NOT IN (lista_usuarios);
    ...
END $$;
```

Sin embargo siempre obtengo este error:
   `ERROR: cannot cast type integer to integer[]`

También he intentado anteponiendo la palabra `array` obteniendo el mismo resultado:

```
lista_usuarios integer[] = array(...)
```

Comment: porque repites el  CREATE?

Answer (score 2):

Tienes varios errores de sintaxis en tu código, por ejemplo, repites `CREATE` dos veces:
`CREATE` <s>`CREATE`</s> `MATERIALIZED VIEW ...`

Luego, para asignar valores al array, puedes hacerlo así:

```
lista_usuarios integer[] = 
(SELECT ARRAY (SELECT usuario_id FROM usuario WHERE estado = 'ACTIVO'));
```

**Código de ejemplo**

### <kbd>[**VER DEMO REXTESTER**](http://rextester.com/UUJTH57887)</kbd>

He simplificado los `CREATE VIEW` por motivos de brevedad...

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS usuario
    (usuario_id serial primary key, 
     usuario varchar(50), 
     estado varchar(7))
;


INSERT INTO usuario
    (usuario_id, usuario, estado)
VALUES
    (1, 'Pedro', 'ACTIVO'),
    (2, 'Santiago', 'OFF'),
    (3, 'Juna', 'ACTIVO')
;

SELECT * FROM usuario;

DO 
$$DECLARE 
    lista_usuarios integer[] = 
    (SELECT ARRAY (SELECT usuario_id FROM usuario WHERE estado = 'ACTIVO'));
BEGIN
    CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW cuentas_con_usuarios_activos AS
    SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE estado = 'OFF';

    CREATE  MATERIALIZED VIEW cuentas_con_usuarios_inactivos AS
    SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE  estado = 'ACTIVO';
END$$;

-- Probando las vistas creadas --

SELECT * FROM cuentas_con_usuarios_activos;
SELECT * FROM cuentas_con_usuarios_inactivos;
```

**Resultado**

```
    usuario_id  usuario estado
1   1           Pedro   ACTIVO
2   2           Santiago    OFF
3   3           Juna    ACTIVO

    usuario_id  usuario estado
1   2           Santiago    OFF

    usuario_id  usuario estado
1   1           Pedro   ACTIVO
2   3           Juna    ACTIVO
```